# IMG1 not defined in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm running into an issue with an image swap script I'm working on. It works beautifully in Chrome and IE 8 but in Firefox I'm getting IMG1 Not Defined. I've tried using `var image1 = document.getElementById("IMG1")` but then I just get image1 is NULL. Any help on this would be appreciated. Here's my code and markup.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function imgSwap() {
        IMG1.src = "/images/stories/clubpics_on.png";
        IMG2.src = "/images/stories/facebook_off.png";
        return(false);  
}
function imgSwap2() {
        IMG1.src = "/images/stories/clubpics_off.png";
        IMG2.src = "/images/stories/facebook_on.png";
        return(false);
        }
</script>

  <img src="/images/stories/clubpics_on.png" name="IMG1" id="IMG1" class="IMG1" style="position:absolute; left:-19px; width:165px" value="IMG1" onclick="imgSwap();"/ >

<img src="/images/stories/facebook_off.png" class="IMG2" value="IMG2" name="IMG2" id="IMG2" style="position:relative; left:123px; width:165px"  onclick="imgSwap2();" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox does not automatically create global references to elements that have "id" values. Use `document.getElementById("IMG1")` instead.

If you tried that assignment statement for the variable "image1" **outside** the two functions, the variable would be `null` because that code would run **before** the element were added to the DOM.  If you put that code **inside** the functions, it will work.

Comment: @Ibu probably he had the assignment outside the functions, which would run before the elements became part of the DOM.

Comment: @Ibu on first pass/click it may dosn't work well on FF3 that is, not until you for example click the second time it gets reference to it.